# Idea behind partial derivative with respect to space multiplied by length

Tags: pressure, calculus

Let $p$ be the pressure in the center of a volume.

If $\delta\,x$ is the volume width, then the pressure on the wall can be expressed as

$$p+\frac{\partial\,p}{\partial\,x}\frac{\delta\,x}{2}$$

My question: Why is that? More precisely:

- Which assumption about the pressure must be applied in order to be able to carry out such a form of 'summation' over a distance?
- Can the formula be applied to other physical quantities? If so, to which quantities? Could I say that

$$T+\frac{\partial\,T}{\partial\,x}\frac{\delta\,x}{2}$$ ? Is this approach limited to scalar quantities? Could I say that it is valid for *additive* (extensive) quantities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, you don't really need to know much about pressure, just calculus.

The idea of a derivative is that it's a kind of "sensitivity" of one quantity to changes in another. What $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x_0)$ *means* is that if you know the pressure at one point $p(x_0)$, and want to know the pressure close to it, at $p(x_0 + \delta x)$, then that pressure is approximately:

$$
p(x_0 + \Delta x) \approx p(x_0) + \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x_0)\right) \Delta x
$$

This is just a rearrangement of how you calculate the derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x_0) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{p(x_0 + \Delta x) - p(x_0)}{\Delta x}
$$

Mathematically, the derivative is what you approach in the limit for very small $\delta x$. Physically, you have to make a guess, based on the specific situation, whether a given $\delta x$ is likely to be small enough for the approximation to work well enough for a given purpose.

All of this works with pressure, but also with any quantity you can add together and multiply by a number (mathematically speaking, the possible values of the quantity must form a linear space). That includes vectors, matrices, complex numbers, and almost anything else you may think up.

Physically speaking, you need the quantity to be continuous, but it doesn't matter what its meaning is: it can be pressure, temperature, the electric field, etc. But it must be defined *locally*, which extensive quantities (like volume or mass) are not, so you are more likely looking for intensive quantities (which all of my examples are).

A picture might help:

[image: linear (affine) approximation of a function]

The approximation is a guess that the function $f(x)$ around a point $a$ looks similar to its tangent line through $a$. As you can see, the approximation works for small displacements and starts to fail further out.

In your example, $\Delta x = \frac{\delta x}{2}$, because that is the distance between the center of the volume and the side. The sign depends on whether the change in $x$ is positive or negative: in the picture, moving to the left of $a$ leads to a decrease in $f$, while moving to the right causes an increase.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you.

Comment: I have a follow up question (if you want to answer): The pressure exerted on the opposite wall is calculated using p - del... . Why is there a changing sign?

Comment: I added a picture, does it help?

Comment: Yes! I had asked myself whether one has to assume that the pressure increases with increasing x (which is apparently the case).

Comment: For a pressure decreasing with $x$, it works the same, the derivative is just a negative number. Then, if $\Delta x$ is positive, pressure drops, while if it is negative, pressure rises because the product of two negative numbers is positive.